# How to implement gesture recognition in android wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os

Hello i'm looking for how to detect gestures in android wear, in android i use some code like this, but doesn't work in android wear.. is there a way to override the default gestures actions or just recognize them?

I'm doing just like google developers: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naf_WbtFAlY
http://youtu.be/sha_w3_5c2c?t=25m1s
Is there something wrong with the emulator? (i'm using 32bit emulator: `emulator -avd AndroidWearXC -force-32bit`)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    private static String DEBUG_TAG="MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onLongPress: " + event.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG," onDown: " + event.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                                   float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                                    float distanceY) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onShowPress: " + event.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)  || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }


}
```

I want swipe left and right, and scroll upp and down gestures:
[image]

**Solved! check my answer..**

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly is not working? Are you not receiving any touch events inside your Activity?

Comment: Exactly, can't receive anything!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After one day i got it to work, the lost part was that i must disable the Swipe-To-Dismiss Gesture and add DismissOverlayView to my layout, steps:

1. Disable the Swipe-To-Dismiss Gesture
   add AppTheme style to your styles.xml and use it as app style in your mainfest

styles.xml:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
    </style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

2. Add DissmissOverlayView to your main layout

   ```
       <android.support.wearable.view.DismissOverlayView 
       android:id="@+id/dismiss_overlay"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
   ```
3. Use it in your activity like this to get gestures

   ```
       public class WearActivity extends Activity {
       private DismissOverlayView mDismissOverlay;
       private GestureDetector mDetector;

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
           super.onCreate(savedState);
           setContentView(R.layout.wear_activity);

           // Obtain the DismissOverlayView element
           mDismissOverlay = (DismissOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.dismiss_overlay);
           mDismissOverlay.setIntroText(R.string.long_press_intro);
           mDismissOverlay.showIntroIfNecessary();

           // Configure a gesture detector
           mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

           @Override
           public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {

               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onLongPress: " + event.toString());
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG," onDown: " + event.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                                  float velocityX, float velocityY) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                                   float distanceY) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onShowPress: " + event.toString());
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
               Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, " onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
               return true;
           }
           });
       }

       // Capture long presses
       @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
           return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
       } 
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked your code? It works fine. For simple action there is SimpleOnGestureListener that you can use to seed up work (it works on Android Wear as well):

```
    GestureDetector mDetector;
    mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        //http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html
//For example:
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent ev) {
                    //TODO handle your action
                }
            });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i'm doing the exact things but nothing move! i must use DimissOverlayView?

Comment: Strange, I have tried and it worked without DismissOverlayView.
Take a look here https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/exit.html#long-press 
or here http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/10/android-wear-dismissoverlayview.htm

Comment: got it, i must put windowSwipeToDismiss to false, i make the solution in new answer to help someone, thank you your link was helpful :)