# How can I scroll up/down for android watch in application?

Tags: android, wear-os, watch

I want to learn how can I scroll/swipe it up or down. I'm using viewPager to scroll right. But it is not proper to up/down swiping or I could not

Comment: hi, I learned that how to do that requirement. I handle it with GestureDetection onFling method. This link may also help you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931510/android-gesture-detection-swipe-up-down-on-particular-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html) which contains information to help it locate a matching view at runtime. You can use the methods [boolean swipeDown (int steps)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html#swipeDown(int)) and [boolean swipeUp (int steps)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiObject.html#swipeUp(int)). You can also check this related SO question - [How to implement gesture recognition in android wear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524418/how-to-implement-gesture-recognition-in-android-wear). You must disable the Swipe-To-Dismiss Gesture and add DismissOverlayView to your layout.

Comment: however, it causes some performans problems because of movement calculation time on fling method